# Swift 2.0 error handling

Tags: swift, error-handling, swift2

My code is below.

```
enum NutritionalError: ErrorType {
    case NotEnoughNutrients
    case TooMuchNutrients
    case Other
}
```

As you can see I have a NutritionalError of ErrorType with three different cases.

I have an error handling function that runs as such.

```
func needs(fat: Double, carbohydrate: Double, protein: Double) throws {
    let totalPercent = fat + carbohydrate + protein

    guard totalPercent > 1 else {
        throw NutritionalError.TooMuchNutrients
    }

    guard totalPercent < 1 else {
        throw NutritionalError.NotEnoughNutrients
    }
}

func calculateNeeds(calories: Int, fatPercent: Double, carbohydratePercent: Double, proteinPercent: Double) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
    do {
        try needs(fatPercent, carbohydrate: carbohydratePercent, protein: proteinPercent)
    } catch NutritionalError.NotEnoughNutrients {
        print("Not enought nutrients.")
    } catch NutritionalError.TooMuchNutrients {
        print("Too many nutrients.")
    }
}
```

At the line.

```
            try needs(fatPercent, carbohydrate: carbohydratePercent, protein: proteinPercent)
```

I am getting an error of.

```
'Errors thrown from here are not handled because the enclosing catch is not exhaustive'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the error states, you need to add a final `catch` without constraints.

Comment: thank you. I just found that but I think a lot of people will have this problem so I am going to keep it up.  Also I took a look at your profile and resume and I must say Impressive!

Comment: That's actually not what the error states. It states it's "not exhaustive" which could mean many things, not just that a non-constrained catch is required.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to be adding this line.

```
catch {
     print("Another error")
}
```

So you must have a catch statement for everything.

Comment: Yes, Swift tries to cover all possibilities, the same with `switch` statements.

Comment: Actually you can use a 'catch Other' instead. The point is to be exhaustive (all possibilities) not just a generic catch anything.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you catch all the errors individually, the compiler still thinks there could be an error that could pass through that block.  I am not an expert in swift, but find a way to catch all encompassing errors like `catch (Error e)` (that's an example and will probably not work)

Answer (score 0):

I thought he missed adding this line:

catch NutritionalError.error

Comment: No, that doesn't solve the problem at all. But, adds the error 'enum case for 'error' not found in type 'ErrorType'' and still doesn't solve the original error.